# Looking for downloadable LGBTQ+ datasets

Tags: data-request, data.gov, uses-of-open-data, data, large-datasets

I have been searching for datasets about LGBTQ+ Americans. I am looking for any file types. I am searching for datasets that look at both mental and behavioral health for LGBT individuals. I appreciate any suggestions and/or help. Thank you!